# How can I move Dashboard widgets to the desktop in Lion?

Tags: terminal, macos, dashboard

In the OS X Terminal, there is a command that allows me to drag Dashboard widgets onto my desktop. In OS X Lion, the Dashboard became a Space. I am no longer able to use this command. What is a workaround to this?

The command is:

```
    defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES
    killall Dock
```

Comment: Hi GurpreetSingh

The Stack Overflow site is intended for questions related to software development. Because this question is more concerned with usage of OS X, you might get better responses from our Apple-specific site AskDifferent or our more general computing site Super User

Comment: You can look through the .plist file for the Dashboard and change the value manually. If I recall correctly, the .plist files are under `~/Library/Preferences/` and contain XML markup. I'd look up the file and value for you, but my Mac died a few weeks ago, and I'm on Ubuntu now.

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences -> MIssion Control, and uncheck 'Show Dashboard as a space.'

Then do exactly what you did before.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, and I'm flabbergasted that I'd never thought of that.